# Parse map by JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json

I have some object with map data and I need to convert it to JSON.
I am using JSON.stringify() method, but after conversion I am getting next result:

```
{"someval":1,"someval2":"blabla","my_map":["{\"email\":\"test@gmail.com\",\"fullName\":\"username\"}"],"moredata":""}
```

I need to get clear string for `my_map`, without extra '\' characters. How I can remove them? Just replace doesn't works because other values can have such characters.

Comment: You can use replace(regex)

Comment: @SirwanAfifi, that would break the JSON.

Comment: No, do NOT use any sort of regex or replaced method. JSON processing should be done only by JSON methods

Comment: @SirwanAfifi that is a terrible suggestion

Comment: If you can, try adding a `toJSON()` method to the object representing the map data, or wrap it in an object that implements `toJSON()`. According to the `JSON.strigify()` docs, this should work. When parsing such data, you will also need to use a revive function supplied to `JSON.parse()` in order to reverse the effect. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Why does it have to be a string? It’s very unusual to have a JSON string inside JSON. There isn’t really any benefit to do that. `my_map` should simply be an array containing an object, not a string. But if you really want it to be a string then the inner `”` have to be escaped. There is no way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `my_map` is already *JSON*. To be exact I need to see the original map object, however the example below will provide enough insight to solve your problem with.

```js
//correct example of a JavaScript object
var map = {"someval":1,"someval2":"blabla","my_map":[{"email":"test@gmail.com","fullName":"username"}],"moredata":""};

//also correct but the array content in my_map is a string and not treated as an object.
var map2 = {"someval":1,"someval2":"blabla","my_map":["{\"email\":\"test@gmail.com\",\"fullName\":\"username\"}"],"moredata":""};

console.log(JSON.stringify(map));   //correctly parsed
console.log(JSON.stringify(map2));  //incorrectly parsed

//solution for two:
//convert the string (JSON) to array and stringify result
map2["my_map"] = JSON.parse(map2["my_map"]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(map2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

In this case `my_map` contains an array which contains a string which needs to be JSON parsed. So to get the string you can do `my_map[0]`. See example:

```js
var x = {"someval":1,"someval2":"blabla","my_map":["{\"email\":\"test@gmail.com\",\"fullName\":\"username\"}"],"moredata":""};

var xx = JSON.parse(x.my_map[0]);

console.log('1: ' + xx.email);
console.log('2: ' + xx.fullName);
```